# Is it possible to build part of executables for exec platform and use them as toolchain for target platform?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have some questions regarding bazel platforms and toolchains. I am currently trying to do the following things:

- Build clang via Bazel rules
- Use this clang as part of cc_toolchain
- Build other rules, which aren't related to llvm toolchain, via this new toolchain.
- Make all these 3 steps above via one 'build bazel ...:*' command.

So, is it possible? To build some part of executables (cc_binary, cc_library) for the exec platform and then use them as a part of the toolchain to build other executables for the target platform by using one 'bazel build' call? Or is it only possible to do such things only with several bazel calls?

I was trying to do such a thing with platforms and platform transitions, but couldn't figure out how to do this.
Do you have any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to compile tools to be used in another toolchain all in one Bazel invocation. I have a toolchain + platforms toy I pasted below that demos this.

The trickier thing is how to get this to work with the cc_toolchain. It might help to reach out to bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com with what you have so far and what's not working.

See also 
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html 
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html

---

`BUILD`:

```
load(":printself.bzl", "printself_toolchain", "printself_binary")

cc_binary(
  name = "printself_compiler_dos",
  srcs = ["printself_compiler_dos.c"],
)

py_binary(
  name = "printself_compiler_dos_py",
  srcs = ["printself_compiler_dos.py"],
  main = "printself_compiler_dos.py",
)

constraint_setting(name = "os")
constraint_setting(name = "cpu")

constraint_value(
  name = "dos",
  constraint_setting = ":os",
)

constraint_value(
  name = "8086",
  constraint_setting = ":cpu",
)

platform(
  name = "dos_8086",
  constraint_values = [
    ":dos",
    ":8086"
  ],
)

toolchain_type(name = "printself_toolchain_type")

printself_toolchain(
  name = "printself_toolchain",
  compiler = ":printself_compiler_dos",
)

toolchain(
    name = "printself_toolchain_dos_8086",
    target_compatible_with = [
        ":dos",
        ":8086",
    ],
    toolchain = ":printself_toolchain",
    toolchain_type = ":printself_toolchain_type",
)

printself_binary(
  name = "hello",
  src = "input.txt",
)
```

`printself.bzl`:

```
def _printself_impl(ctx):
  compiler = ctx.toolchains["//:printself_toolchain_type"].compiler
  out = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".com")
  ctx.actions.run(
      outputs = [out],
      inputs = [ctx.files.src[0]],
      arguments = [ctx.files.src[0].path, out.path],
      executable = compiler.files_to_run,
  )

  return DefaultInfo(files = depset([out]))

printself_binary = rule(
  implementation = _printself_impl,
  attrs = {
    "src": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
  },
  toolchains = ["//:printself_toolchain_type"]
)

def _printself_toolchain_impl(ctx):
    toolchain_info = platform_common.ToolchainInfo(
        compiler = ctx.attr.compiler,
    )
    return [toolchain_info]

printself_toolchain = rule(
    implementation = _printself_toolchain_impl,
    attrs = {
        "compiler": attr.label(mandatory = True, executable = True, cfg = "exec"),
    },
)
```

`printself_compiler_dos.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// "compiles" a txt file to a "self printing" text file
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("input and output filenames needed\n");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("compiling %s\n", argv[1]);

  FILE* src = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (src == NULL) {
    printf("could not open input file");
    return 1;
  }
  char srcbuff[255];
  if (fgets(srcbuff, 255, src) == NULL) {
    printf("could not read input file");
    fclose(src);
    return 1;
  }
  fclose(src);

  char prog[] = {
    /* mov ax, 9   */ 0xB4, 0x09,
    /* mov dx, msg */ 0xBA, 0x08, 0x01, // 0x0108 is byte after ret
    /* int 21h     */ 0xCD, 0x21,
    /* ret         */ 0xC3,
    /* msg: db "$" */ 
  };
  
  FILE* out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
  fwrite(prog, 1, 8, out);
  fputs(srcbuff, out);
  fputc('$', out); // $ terminated string
  fclose(out);

  printf("wrote %s\n", argv[2]);
  printf("done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

`WORKSPACE`:

```
register_toolchains("//:printself_toolchain_dos_8086")
```

`input.txt`:

```
hello world!
```

usage:

```
bazel build hello --platforms=//:dos_8086
dosbox bazel-bin/hello.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
After my question I tried to use two explicit cc toolchains (first for host toolchain and second for custome clang toolchain) together with two different platform with different constrainsts and used platform transition for targets which should be built via clang tooclhain, it seems to be work, but your solution seems to be easy, I wiil try this too, thanks!